# How to remove the comma (,) between two words using Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

How to remove the comma (,) between two words?

How can I place those two words in two different rows?

This is my input:

```
ent0
ent4
ent1,ent5
ent2,ent6
ent3,ent7
ent29,ent30
```

Comment: There's a good chance you don't need to, and can set the field separator for the next command to include commas.

Answer (score 16):

```
tr ',' '\n'
```

would replace all `,`s in your input file with line breaks, that sounds like it is what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Use `tr`:

```
$  tr ',' '\n' < FILE
ent0
ent4
ent1
ent5
ent2
ent6
ent3
ent7
ent29
ent30
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line; do 
    echo "${line//,/$'\n'}";
done <infile.txt
```

or `sed`

```
sed -e $'s/,/\\\n/g' infile.txt
```

or

```
sed 's/,/\
/g' infile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

In case there may be spaces or other blank characters around the comma - ***sed*** solution:

```
sed 's/[[:blank:]]*,[[:blank:]]*/\
/g' file
```

With some `sed` implementations, you can replace the `\<newline>` with `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cut` as follow:

I don't know where your data come from. But I'm sure you can pipe your info to `cut`:

```
cat yourfile.data | cut -d, --output-delimiter ' ' -f 1,2
```

as per  `man cut`

```
...
-d, --delimiter=DELIM
       use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
--output-delimiter=STRING
       use STRING as the output delimiter the default is to use the input delimiter
-f, --fields=LIST
       select only these fields;  also print any line that contains no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
...
```

But, if you need to add further logic I recommend you to use `sed` as @RomanPerekhrest said. You will have a more flexible way to parse your data with powerful regular expressions. In my opinion, the best regular expression for doing this would be:

```
'/^\s*\([^,]\+\)\s*,\s*([^,]\+\)\s*$/'
```

~ 0 or more spaces followed of anything but comma, followed of 0 or more spaces, comma, 0 or more spaces followed of anything but comma, followed of 0 or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'll want to keep the column structure, here's how to only get commas substituted by spaces.

In bash:

```
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2; do
    printf "%s %s\n" "$field1" "$field2"
done < test.txt
```

Reference: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 0):

With the use of `tr`(on the specific case that you provided) you can translate the `comma` to `new line`

```
user@server[/test]> cat text.txt
ent0
ent4
ent1,ent5
ent2,ent6
ent3,ent7
ent29,ent30
user@server[/test]> cat text.txt| tr "," "\n"
ent0
ent4
ent1
ent5
ent2
ent6
ent3
ent7
ent29
ent30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat /tmp/sample.txt
one,two, three
four, five,six
```

**tr command options:**

- Remove comma (,)
- Remove newline (\n)
- Remove empty space (' ')

Below is the output:

```
$ cat /tmp/sample.txt | tr "," "\n" | tr -d ' '
one
two
three
four
five
six
```